# Outlook addin - trigger on incoming messages (js)

Tags: office365, outlook-web-addins

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest) for event-based triggering in Outlook add-ins only lists events for created and sent messages.

Is there no way to trigger on received messages?

Answer (score 0):

No, not in JS-based Web addins. If you want to handle received messages, VSTO/COM addin (Windows desktop Outlook only) is your only option.